# How to forward path along with port

Tags: port-forwarding, aws, amazon-ec2, https

I'm willing to bet I have a fundamental misunderstanding here, but I am trying to do something akin to port-forwarding AND url-forwarding without using something like nginx.

I have a remote linux instance (EC2) that can connect to a database (Neptune) on port 8182. Only the instance can connect to Neptune, I cannot connect directly from my localhost. I also have a UI tool for the database (GraphExp) that works by connecting to my localhost port 8182, and I want that UI tool to connect to the database through my remote instance.

UI --> localhost:8182 --> ec2-instance.amazonaws.com:8182 --> neptune-db.amazonaws.com:8182/gremlin

The problem is that, in order for a query to the database to work, it has to be sent to the `/gremlin` path.

For example, if I am SSH'ed onto the EC2 instance, I can successfully query the database with the following command

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type:application/json' https://db-cluster-url-name.region.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182/gremlin -d '{"gremlin":"g.V().groupCount().by(label)"}'
```

The UI tool, on the other hand, only sends a request to port 8182, with no path. I have tried setting up port-forwarding as follows:

```
ssh -vL 8182:db-cluster-url-name.region.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182 -i key.pem ec2-user@my-ec2-instance.region.compute.amazonaws.com
```

However, the request gets forwarded to `db-cluster-url-name.region.neptune.amazonaws.com:8182` without the `/gremlin` path.

How can I set up a relationship between these servers so that requests to my local port 8182 get forwarded to the database's port 8182 *with the appended path*?

Ideally, I would like a solution that involves unix commands that are preinstalled or come with package managers, so that I can avoid heavier technologies like NGinX. But I'll start with anything that works, beggars can't be choosers. :-)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If I understand correctly the path is part of the HTTP request, the rest is just forwarding. If your originator (the program that generates the request) isn't requesting `/gremlin` then no forwarding will change that - unless you do request rewriting which is something that proxies and HTTP daemons can do - e.g. `nginx`.

Comment: *"The UI tool, on the other hand, only sends a request to port 8182, with no path."*  Forgive my ignorance, but why doesn't the UI tool send the request to the correct path?  If this is true, the tool wouldn't work directly on the instance that can access the endpoint, either, so the fact that you happen to need an SSH tunnel isn't really a relevant factor... so the question seems to be about that discrepancy.  How does anyone use the tool if it doesn't work properly?